# FactoryGirl with multiple references to the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following model:

```
class ProfileAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :destination_profile, :class_name => "Profile"

  attr_accessible :profile_id, :destination_profile_id
end
```

I want to create a factory for this simple class.

This is what I have:

THis is my Profile factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    name "MyString"
  end

  factory :destination_profile do
    name "Other profile"
  end
end
```

And this is my ProfileAssignment factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile_assignment do
    profile 
    association :destination_profile, factory: :destination_profile 
  end
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.create(:profile_assignment).valid?).to be_true
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant DestinationProfile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining factory `destination_profile` for Profile class, then you will have to mention the class explicitly.

Factory girl tries to initialize the class based on the factory name. So if you name your factory as destination_profile, it will look for a class named DestinationProfile. Provide class information to the destination_profile factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    name "MyString"
  end

  factory :destination_profile, :class => Profile do
    name "Other profile"
  end
end
```

Also you don't have to specify the factory explicitly, if your association name matches the factory name

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile_assignment do
    profile 
    association :destination_profile
  end
end
```

Have a loot at [rspec traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits) if you want multiple factories for the same class.